# Pivot Table considers duplicate elements for the average calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a pivot table (with Data Model) based on below table

```
Id  |  Time
 1  |  10
 1  |  10
 1  |  10
 2  |  2
 3  |  5
 3  |  5
 4  |  4
 5  |  8
```

I need to calculate the average of time.

Average based on the pivot table calculation is `6.75` --> `(10*3+2+5*2+4+8)/8`

However, my expected result is `5.8` --> `(10+2+5+4+8)/5`

How can I setup the pivot table to not take into consideration the duplicate ?

Please note that I can't remove duplicate rows.

I tried to use `AVERAGEX` : `=AVERAGEX(VALUES('Range'[Id]);'Range'[Time])` with DAX.

But I'm facing this issue: `This formula is invalid or incomplete: 'Calculation error in measure 'Range'[475e7fe7-92b4-478c-bd5f-6e7c95df27d7]: A single value for column 'Time' in table 'Range' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.'.`

Thank you in advance !

**Solution**

`=AVERAGEX(VALUES('Range'[Id]);CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Range'[Time])))`

Comment: With a formula `=AVERAGE(INDEX(UNIQUE(A2:B9),0,2))`

Comment: @JvdV thank you for your comment. I agree with this formula. However, I need to have the measure in the PivotTable directly because I will do some grouping based on other critieria (this is the next step). My usage of `AVERAGEX` is not correct?

Comment: I posted the solution in the question ! Thank you.

Comment: there is nothing that stops you from posting an answer to your question yourself, instead of editing the question. It may benefit others in the future if you do so.

Comment: Yes in 2 days, I'm not able to do it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
=AVERAGEX(VALUES('Range'[Id]);CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Range'[Time])))
```